# Why does this code produce "Segmentation fault: 11" error?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

The compiler throws this error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

On following code:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

...

FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

     if error != nil {
       print("error signing in")
     }
     else {
       print("sign in succeeded")
     }
})
```

For testing, the code is running a viewDidLoad. When I comment out the above code, everything builds fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

-- EDIT ---
This error is randomly showing up. After clean/build, sometimes it is there and sometimes not.

Comment: What's the type of `error` in completion handler?

Comment: I'm confused; you say the app is crashing but then say "When I comment out the above code, everything builds fine.".  Is the app crashing or the compiler?

Comment: your Firebase cocoapods is up to date?

Comment: It's a compiler time error. The app isn't able to run. Yes - cocoapods is up to date.

Comment: Is this inside of some other function? You can't have a function declaration hanging around in its own scope.

Comment: In a function and I tried it viewDidLoad. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Latest thing: Did Product > Analyze, which also did a successful build. But a little while later didn't compile again with fault 11 error.